# grouping by date ranges

Tags: r, date

This would seem to be a simple task but I'm having difficulty executing it as well as finding examples of how it is done in R.

I have a data frame with about 75K records. One field has dates and it goes back about 11 years.  I've used the following code to strip off the hours minutes seconds so I just have year-month-day

```
 dat$date=round.POSIXt(dat$date,units="day")
```

I am now trying to create a new field "FiscalYear" based on dates such that if the date is between 2008-07-01 and 2009-06-30 it gets assigned FY09...then between 2009-07-01 and 2010-06-30 it gets assigned to FY10, etc...

The method I've been trying is with ifelse using >= && <= to set the date ranges but this isn't working.  Any thoughts?

Comment: `?cut.Date`, `?seq.Date`, `?cut` (for the `labels` argument)

Comment: And you can just use `as.Date()` to get a `Date` object from one of the `POSIXt` classes. (e.g. `Sys.time(); as.Date(Sys.time())`.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically, what Ben said. Here's an example of what that'd look like in practice. (I've used a `Date` class object, since it sounds like you don't need the hour/minute/second info.)

```
date <- seq(from = as.Date("2010/5/30"), by="week", length=10) ## Example data

cuts <- seq(from = as.Date("2000/7/1"), by="year", length=13) 
labs <- paste0("FY", 1:12)

cut(date, breaks = cuts, labels = labs)
#  [1] FY10 FY10 FY10 FY10 FY10 FY11 FY11 FY11 FY11 FY11
# Levels: FY1 FY2 FY3 FY4 FY5 FY6 FY7 FY8 FY9 FY10 FY11 FY12
```

Comment: my data isn't in sequence.  doesn't something need to look at the date field to determine which FY to assign?

Comment: There's no need for your data to be in a sequence. `seq()` was just a quick way to generate some example data. As long as you take care to get the `cuts` and `labs` to match up correctly, this will work just fine. (I *would* suggest testing out whatever you use with a range of dates, replacing `date` with `as.Date("2010/6/30")`, `as.Date("2010/7/1")`, `as.Date("1998/1/1")`, etc. to see that it works as you expect.)

Comment: Got it.  Works smooth, thank you.  I tinkered with it and screwed it up but figured out that the length of the "cuts" needs to be 1 more than the length of "labs".  In Labs, would you know how to have a leading zero for years with one digit?  FY01 instead of FY1?

Comment: `labs <- sprintf("FY%02s",  1:12)`

Comment: `paste0("FY", formatC(1:12, width=2, flag="0"))` will also work.

Comment: For me, the sprintf function left an empty space on FY 1 to FY 9.  formatC did the trick Fy01 to FY09